# Как изменить текст надписи «Чтобы активировать Windows перейдите к параметрам компьютера»?

Tags: windows

Как изменить текст надписи

> "Чтобы активировать Windows перейдите к параметрам компьютера"

Вбивал в поиск в реестре эту фразу, но что-то не получилось найти. Знаю, что полностью отключить этот водяной знак можно в реестре если открыть

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT \CurrentVersion\SoftwareProtectionPlatform\Activation
```

Comment: 1.активировать винду 2.я не за пиратство, но в интернете нет ключей активации?

Comment: думаю, тут все скажут, активировать :)

Comment: Думаю все скажут, что выше комментаторы, читать не умеют. Написано, как изменить эту надпись. А по делу, нужно найти этот водяной знак в файлах системы и отфотошопить, как душе захочется, в плоть до полной перерисовки.

Comment: Изменить надпись на пустую строку?)))